# Cocos2d's "self.isTouchEnable = YES" is error,what's worry with it?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

In Cocos2d's CCLayer class init function, "self.isTouchEnable=YES"is not useful with a error: request for member 'isTouchEnable' in something not a structure or union.What's worry with it?
And registerWithTouchDispatcher funntion can't be used too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
   [self setIsTouchEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

isTouchEnable is a method. You should write [self setIsTouchEnable:YES];

Do refer some good books on objective c.

Comment: Well...it is SORT OF a method.  Really it is a property, which synthesizes into two methods.  The other answer is correct.